# Porque se ejecuta dos veces el método onCreate al sustituir un Fragment dentro del viewPager?

Tags: android, android-fragment, viewpager

Tengo un adapter llamado ProvinciaAdapter en el cual al seleccionar un elemento me devuelve su nombre y lo pasa a la actividad principal de la siguiente manera

public class ProvinciaAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter {

```
private Context context;
private ArrayList<Provincia> provincias;


public ProvinciaAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Provincia> provincias) {
    this.context = context;
    this.provincias = provincias;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.item_card_provincias, parent, false);
    return new MyViewHolder(v);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Provincia provincia = provincias.get(position);
    holder.bindData(provincia);

    holder.setOnClickListeners();
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {

    return provincias.size();
}
```

public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

```
    Context context;
    View view;
    TextView txtNombre, txtcantMunicipios;

    public MyViewHolder(@NonNull View v) {
        super(v);
        txtNombre = v.findViewById(R.id.txtNombreProvincia);
        txtcantMunicipios = v.findViewById(R.id.txtCantMunicipios);
        context = v.getContext();
        view = v;
    }

    public void bindData(final Provincia provincia) {

        txtNombre.setText(provincia.getNombre());
        txtcantMunicipios.setText("Municipios: " + provincia.getCantidadMunicipios());
    }


    public void setOnClickListeners(){
        view.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        // Get the item clicked
        // For this example, I'm assuming your data source is of type `List<MyObject>`

        Provincia provincia = provincias.get(getAdapterPosition());
        // Then you can do any actions on it, for example:
        Toast.makeText(context, "El nombre de esta provincia es " + provincia.getNombre()
                        + " y su cantidad de municipios es " +  provincia.getCantidadMunicipios(),
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();provincia.getNombre();

        Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("provinciaSeleccionada", provincia.getNombre());
        context.startActivity(intent);
    }

}
```

}

En el mi clase MainActivity a traves de metodo onCreate, recibo dicho nombre (de la provincia) y llamo al método openPrincipalFragment, de la siguiente manera:

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener{

```
DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle;
NavigationView navigationView;
ViewPager viewPager;
TabLayout tabLayout;
TabsPagerHomeAdapter pagerHomeAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    viewPager = findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
    tabLayout = findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);
    poblarViewPager(viewPager);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

    drawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

    toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout, toolbar, R.string.open, R.string.close);
    drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(true);
    toggle.syncState();


    String provinciaSeleccionada = getIntent().getStringExtra("provinciaSeleccionada");
    if(provinciaSeleccionada != null){
        openPrincipalFragment(provinciaSeleccionada);
    }

}

private void poblarViewPager(ViewPager viewPager)
{

    TabsPagerHomeAdapter tabsPagerHomeAdapter = new TabsPagerHomeAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), FragmentPagerAdapter.BEHAVIOR_RESUME_ONLY_CURRENT_FRAGMENT);
    tabsPagerHomeAdapter.agregarFragmentoYTitulo(new PrincipalFragment(), getString(R.string.titulo_tab_principal));
    tabsPagerHomeAdapter.agregarFragmentoYTitulo(new ListaProductosFragment(), getString(R.string.titulo_tab_listado_productos));
    tabsPagerHomeAdapter.agregarFragmentoYTitulo(new AlertaNotificacionesFragment(), getString(R.string.titulo_tab_alertas_notificaciones));
    tabsPagerHomeAdapter.agregarFragmentoYTitulo(new PremiosFragment(), getString(R.string.titulo_tab_premios));
    viewPager.setAdapter(tabsPagerHomeAdapter);

}

public void openPrincipalFragment(String text){
    PrincipalFragment principalFragment = PrincipalFragment.newInstance(text);
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.enter_from_right, R.anim.exit_to_right,R.anim.enter_from_right, R.anim.exit_to_right);
    fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
    fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.viewPager,principalFragment).commit();
}

private void agregarToolbar() {
    Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    final ActionBar ab = getSupportActionBar();
    if (ab != null) {
        // Poner ícono del drawer toggle
        ab.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.drawer_toggle);
        ab.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer =  findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
    drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    switch (item.getItemId()){
        case R.id.principal:
            Toast.makeText(this, "Menu Principal Seleccionado", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        case R.id.cuenta:
            Toast.makeText(this, "Menu Cuenta Seleccionado", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        case R.id.configuracion:
            Toast.makeText(this, "Menu Configuracion Seleccionado", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    return false;
}
```

}

Al debugear el codigo me doy cuenta que al ejecutarse una primera ves, el textView (textViewProvinciaSelect) que quiero que tome el valor del nombre de la provincia toma correctamente dicho valor, pero posteriormente se ejecuta el nuevamente el método onCreate y por lo tanto la variable mText no toma valor y por consecuente tampoco el  textView (textViewProvinciaSelect).Aqui les dejo un pedazo del codigo del Fragment

public class PrincipalFragment extends Fragment {

```
SliderView sliderView;
SliderAdapterPrincipal adapter;
ExtendedFloatingActionButton efab;
NestedScrollView nestedScrollView;
TextView textViewProvinciaSelect, textViewUsuariosRegistrados, textViewAnunciosPublicados;
Integer provinciaIndex;
int imagen2 = R.drawable.courier2;
private int[] myImageList = new int[]{R.drawable.promocion, R.drawable.navega,
        R.drawable.dominio};

private static final String TEXT = "text";

private String mText;

public PrincipalFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


public static PrincipalFragment newInstance(String text) {
    PrincipalFragment fragment = new PrincipalFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString(TEXT, text);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (getArguments() != null) {
        mText = getArguments().getString(TEXT);
    }

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_principal, container, false);

    textViewProvinciaSelect = view.findViewById(R.id.provinciaSelect);

    if(mText != null){
        textViewProvinciaSelect.setText(mText);
        Utiles utiles = new Utiles();
        provinciaIndex = utiles.getIndexByProvincia(mText);
    }else{
        recuperarPreferenciaProvinciaSelect();
    }

    efab = view.findViewById(R.id.exFb);
    textViewUsuariosRegistrados = view.findViewById(R.id.textViewUsuariosRegistrados);
    textViewAnunciosPublicados = view.findViewById(R.id.textViewAnunciosPublicados);

    sliderView = view.findViewById(R.id.imageSlider);

    adapter = new SliderAdapterPrincipal(getActivity());
    renewItems();
    sliderView.setSliderAdapter(adapter);
    setPropiedadesSlider();

    efab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), AnuncioActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("provinciaIndex", provinciaIndex);
            startActivity(intent);
            getActivity().finish();
        }
    });

    .
    .
    .
```

El adapter ProvinciaAdapter, se esta cargando en la clase ProvinciaActivity. A continuacion pongo un pedazo del codigo de la clase ProvinciaActivity:

public class ProvinciaActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
private ProvinciaAdapter provinciaAdapter;
private ArrayList<Provincia> provinciaArrayList = new ArrayList<>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_provincias);

    agregarToolbar();


    //inicalizar el recyclerview
    RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerViewProvincias);


    //Poblar el arreglo de provincias y crear el adaptador
    poblarListaProvincias();
    ProvinciaAdapter adapter = new ProvinciaAdapter(this, provinciaArrayList);

    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

    GridLayoutManager gridLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getApplicationContext(),2);
    gridLayoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL); // Pasarle la Orientacion
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(gridLayoutManager); // Pasar el layout al recyclerView

    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


}




private void agregarToolbar() {
    final ActionBar ab = getSupportActionBar();
    if (ab != null) {
        // Poner ícono del drawer toggle
        ab.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_arrow_back_black_24dp);
        ab.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        ab.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        ab.setTitle("Seleccionar Provincia");
    }

}


public void poblarListaProvincias(){
    Provincia provincia = new Provincia("Pinar del Río", 11);
    provinciaArrayList.add(provincia);
    provincia = new Provincia("Artemisa", 11);
    provinciaArrayList.add(provincia);
    provincia = new Provincia("La Habana", 15);
    provinciaArrayList.add(provincia);
    provincia = new Provincia("Mayabeque", 11);
    provinciaArrayList.add(provincia);
    provincia = new Provincia("Matanzas", 13);
    provinciaArrayList.add(provincia);
    provincia = new Provincia("Cienfuegos", 8);
    provinciaArrayList.add(provincia);
    provincia = new Provincia("Villa Clara", 13);
    provinciaArrayList.add(provincia);
    provincia = new Provincia("Sancti Spíritus", 8);
    provinciaArrayList.add(provincia);
    provincia = new Provincia("Ciego Ávila", 10);
    provinciaArrayList.add(provincia);
    provincia = new Provincia("Camagüey", 13);
    provinciaArrayList.add(provincia);
    provincia = new Provincia("Las Tunas", 8);
    provinciaArrayList.add(provincia);
    provincia = new Provincia("Granma", 13);
    provinciaArrayList.add(provincia);
    provincia = new Provincia("Holguín", 14);
    provinciaArrayList.add(provincia);
    provincia = new Provincia("Santiago de Cuba", 9);
    provinciaArrayList.add(provincia);
    provincia = new Provincia("Guantánamo", 10);
    provinciaArrayList.add(provincia);
    provincia = new Provincia("Isla de la Juventud", 1);
    provinciaArrayList.add(provincia);
}
```

}

Comment: Revisa en MainActivity si se llama dos ocasiones : lo que se encuentra dentro del if:
    if(provinciaSeleccionada != null){
        openPrincipalFragment(provinciaSeleccionada);
    }  , comentame si es asì. Por cierto en que Activity se esta cargando ProvinciaAdapter?

Comment: ProvinciaAdapter se carga en la actividad ProvinciaActivity, de la cual deje un pedazo de codigo anteriormente en lo ultimo de la publicacion @Jorgesys

Comment: Buenas! Podrías revisar si el problema esta cuando haces click en tu adapter, tal vez se ejecuta dos veces desde ahi. Para ayudar un poco más, podrías agregar las clases completas.

Comment: Aqui puse las clases de mi proyecto. Muchisimas gracias de ante mano. Y aceptaria cualquier otra correccion @rguzman